# Using find with phpQuery

Tags: php, string, match, phpquery

I have just started using phpQuery, and the documentation isn't particularly good and not been able to find many examples on the web.

I simply wanted to pass some html into phpQuery and match a string.

ie.

```
$html = '<div>blah blah blah <a href=1.php>xssss</a></div>';
```

and from here I want to search `$html` for `1.php` if found I should return some text like "found it"

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
  $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
```

> ```
> if(pq($doc)->find('12.php')) {
>    echo 'found it';  
> }else{
>    echo 'not found';
> }
> ```

as the output on this is 'found it'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not css, you want something like `a[href="12.php"]`

Comment: Hi, thanks I have tried that previously (I prob. should have mentioned) but with out success.

Comment: Just read some documentation on css, that's all you need.